# iTunes (Mac) window too large after transfering library. Sizing box outside screen

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, itunes

I transferred an iTunes library to my 2nd computer (copying the Music iTunes folder).  The 2nd computer has a lower screen resolution (20" vs. 24") and now when I open iTunes there the window is too large and the sizing box (right/bottom) is out of reach.

Clicking the green title bar icon does open the mini player rather than adjusting the window to the screen as it does this with other programs.

So how do I get access to the sizing box again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem weeks ago while using a bigger externel screen with my Mac Book pro.

Solution:

Try holding option (alt) and pressing the green maximise button

Comment: Yay ... right on spot.  Caching ... up goes your reputation! :-)  TY

Comment: God bless you...